# regex to get the values based on the dot selection

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have some of the host names as provided below, i am looking to extract only last three names after dot `.`

```
linux7.4q22018.am.nomas.net
uskbkriq01v.na-rdc.pro.com
dtc2233.dti.us-cdc.pro.com
atgrk01labt001v.at-cdc.rci.rs.pro.com
atgrk01labt002v.at-cdc.rci.rs.pro.com
```

**My trial:**

I am using below rgex which extracts everything what what it gets after hostname conatining the first dot `.` itself

```
([?\.].*)
```

**Result**

```
  .4q22018.am.nomas.net
  .na-rdc.pro.com
  .dti.us-cdc.pro.com
  .at-cdc.rci.rs.pro.com
  .at-cdc.rci.rs.pro.com
```

Expected:

```
  am.nomas.net
  na-rdc.pro.com
  us-cdc.pro.com
  rci.rs.pro.com
  rci.rs.pro.com
```

Comment: Are you even trying to write a correct regexp, or just posting a guess so that someone will do it for you? There's nothing in your regexp that counts 3 dots.

Comment: Why do you have `?` in the character set? It's also not necessary to escape `.` when it's inside `[]`.

Comment: @Barmar,  this is correct regex which i am using within splunk, i have tested it on [regex](https://regex101.com/r/hSUvGl/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
```

Each `[^.]+` matches a sequence of non-dot characters. So this matches 3 of them separated by `.`. And `$` makes it match at the end of the string, so it matchest the last 3 groups.